# Why do variables sometimes bind both directions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, binding

Say I have

```
    x = [[0,0]]
    y = x[-1]
```

Then why does

```
    y[1] += 1
```

give

```
    x = [[0,1]]
    y = [0,1]
```

That is, I'm confused as to why it also changes what x is, even though I only specified something to do with y?

Comment: For that, you need to study the *reference of objects in python*(google search)?

Comment: `y` points to the same one object.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense if you think of a list as a mutable object in memory and you consider that you're modifying that list.

The variables are simply different names for that same list.

That code is equivalent to:

```
list_obj = [0, 0]
x = [ list_obj ]    # a list with list_obj as
                    # its single element
y = list_obj        # same as x[-1], just
                    # another name for list_obj
```

Then it's natural that you're simply modifying `list_obj[1]` in both cases.